# How far off should Genetic Algorithm be when solving TSP

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I am learning genetic algorithm and I am practicing on traveling salesman problem.

I am wondering what should i realistically expect GA to be able to do.

I have tried 15 city and 48 city problem here [TSP sample problems](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/tsp_io/tsp_io.html)

My GA finds the exact solution for 15 city problem very fast. However, it struggles with the 48 city problem. I tried various specifications for number of children an population size, and my results are roughly this:

Correct solution minimum distance: 33,551

My GA solution distance: ~39,000

Random Route distnace: ~140,000

I understand that GA is not guaranteed to give the exact solution, but only a solution that is close, which is basically what is happening.

My question is: Is being off by how far I am for 48 city problem OK for GA algorithm or am I doing something wrong and my GA needs some major improvements?

Thank You in Advance

Comment: There exist different configurations. If you e.g. use a permutation to represent the solution the best operator is the Edge recombination crossover (ERX) together with a higher selection pressure (tournament with a reasonable group size). For mutation you should use invert a part of the permutation. I think these are settings that work quite well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bigger the number of cities, the harder the problem, and not just because the search space is bigger, but also because the cost function usually becomes more convoluted.

It is always hard (if not impossible) to say how well an heuristic will perform (not just GAs, but all of them), but 16% off seems to me to be a great deal. I believe that the performance might be improved if you changed the operators and tinkered a bit with the parameters.

Every operator has limitations and expectations about the result. Your crossover operator (as you stated in your previous post), for instance, tends to increase the number of chromosomes with the same subpath, leading to genetic convergence, and the mutation operator you used is not one of the most agressive ones. Ergo, I would suggest that you use other operators and see if performance improves. You can use all the references in my previous answer to you to understand them properly and implementation should not be too hard, for they are simple once you understand them.

Comment: Thank You, I was thinking that I was too far off.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can definitely improve upon that. I would aim for no more than 5% error, preferably `~1%`.